# How to record ping statistics in tabular format?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I need to record the ping statistics into a tabular format on windows.

```
C:\Users\hsangal>ping localhost -t -n 2

Pinging TechBeamers.local [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss)
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

I would like to do it using Windows batch scripting, looking for some lead from the experts. The data that I wish to record in a tabular format is the part of ping command output highlighted below:

> ```
> Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss)
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `find` to get the lines with the information of interest only, like:

```
ping localhost -n 2 | find "Packets:"
```

This returns only the line `Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),`.
Then you wrap around a `for /F` statement like this:

```
for /F "tokens=3,5,7,8 delims=,=() " %I in ('ping localhost -n 2 ^| find "Packets:"') do echo %I;%J;%K;%L
```

The output will then be this (sent packets;received packets;lost packets;% loss):

```
2;2;0;0%
```

Of course you may specify (a) delimiter(s) other than `;` (just exchange in the final `echo` statement).
Regard that the above code works only if directly entered into the command prompt. If you want to use it within a batch file, replace variables `%I` etc. by `%%I`.

**Note:** The `-t` switch in your `ping` command line is ignored when you provide the `-n` switch.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Powershell [Test-Connection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh849808.aspx) command

```
Test-Connection localhost
```

The result is in a tabular format like below:
[image]

If you want to get the # of packets lost, you can do the following.  Suppose you wanted to see how many lost packets out of 5 pings:

```
   $pingCount = 5
   $x = Test-Connection localhost -count $pingCount
   $lostPackets = $pingCount - $x.count
```

Comment: This command is cool. Can it also report the packet loss statistics as ping does?

Comment: Thanks Davies for answering with a new perspective, at least for me. But @aschipfl caught it with bare hands :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do scripting and want to format the outputs you might want to consider Powershell Test-Connection rather. It has way more options to format the output.

Multiple output e.g:
c:> test-connection www.google.co.za, www.yahoo.com

Column selection and exporting are just some of the features. This link provides a good overview: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849808.aspx